# Window opens, catches focus and disappears (WIndows 10)

Tags: windows, window

Since a few days, a window pops randomly up (every 30 min or so) and disappears again. It stays in focus for less than a second and it is impossible to read anything.

It could be related to Firefox or not, it is hard to say... Any idea how to catch this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also been having that since the big update last week. Seems that the OfficeBackgroundTaskHandler is the culprit: https://www.ghacks.net/2017/05/30/what-is-that-popup-on-windows-10-that-disappears-after-a-split-second/

Comment: Thanks, that helped.